# Delete rows in a simplified csv file (one newline per row) based on a specific column value

Tags: awk, csv-simple

I have a csv file with the following headers - Interaction_ID, PDB_ID, First_Residue, First_Chain, Second_Residue, Third_Residue, Third_Chain & Pattern:

```
AM_AUTO_1,1cx0,A166,B,C118,B,G129,B,A-minor Type I ACG                            
AM_AUTO_2,1cx0,A165,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG                           
AM_AUTO_3,1cx0,A166,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG                           
AM_AUTO_4,1ddy,A25,A,C21,A,G8,A,A-minor Type I ACG                            
AM_AUTO_5,1e7k,A33,C,C28,C,G45,C,A-minor Type 0 AGC                            
AM_AUTO_6,1e7k,A33,D,C28,D,G45,D,A-minor Type 0 AAU
```

What I would like to do is delete rows in the csv file where Pattern = %Type 0% and then print the resulting csv file. The result should be like this:

```
AM_AUTO_1,1cx0,A166,B,C118,B,G129,B,A-minor Type I ACG                            
AM_AUTO_2,1cx0,A165,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG                           
AM_AUTO_3,1cx0,A166,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG                           
AM_AUTO_4,1ddy,A25,A,C21,A,G8,A,A-minor Type I ACG
```

How I can do this using awk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`, you can do:

```
$ awk '$(NF-1)!=0' file
AM_AUTO_1,1cx0,A166,B,C118,B,G129,B,A-minor Type I ACG
AM_AUTO_2,1cx0,A165,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG
AM_AUTO_3,1cx0,A166,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG
AM_AUTO_4,1ddy,A25,A,C21,A,G8,A,A-minor Type I ACG
```

or using `grep`:

```
grep -v 'Type 0' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -F, '$9!~/Type 0/{print $0}' file
AM_AUTO_1,1cx0,A166,B,C118,B,G129,B,A-minor Type I ACG
AM_AUTO_2,1cx0,A165,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG
AM_AUTO_3,1cx0,A166,B,C119,B,G128,B,A-minor Type II ACG
AM_AUTO_4,1ddy,A25,A,C21,A,G8,A,A-minor Type I ACG
```

**Explanation:**

This causes `awk` to use `,` as delimiter (`-F,`). If the 9th field doesn't contain "Type 0" (`$9!~/Type 0/`), print the line (`{print $0}`).

And a `sed` solution:

```
sed '/,[^,]*Type 0[^,]*$/d' file
```